# Laravel Eloquent Complex Query get lastest data from one table

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I am creating real time chat system with laravel. I want to get lastest message from the db. I want query like this from eloquent.

```
$senderLastMessage = Message::where('sender_id',$user->id)->where('receiver_id',auth()->user()->id)->latest('created_at')->first();
$receiverLastMessage = Message::where('receiver_id',$user->id)->where('sender_id',auth()->user()->id)->latest('created_at')->first();
```

Now i want the lastest msg in this case the lastest msg will either be send from auth->user or from other user. how can i get this? if i get these seperately. i will have to create date comparisons like check date of senderLastMessage->created_at is greater or receiverLastMessage->created_at is greater or if they are equal then get there time and check whose time is greater and then display that message instance.

How can i get this from eloquent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use OR condition with some parenthesis in your query

```php
$lastMessage = Message::where( fuunction($query) use($user) {
    $query->where('sender_id',$user->id)
        ->orWhere('receiver_id', $user->id);
})->where( function($query) {
    $query->where('sender_id',auth()->id())
        ->orWhere('receiver_id', auth()->id());
})->latest('created_at')->first();
```